# How to delete the first slice photoshop generated while using slice tool?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, slices

I am following a Photoshop tutorial for designing web pages. And after I used the slice tool, I could not delete the following 01 slice. The `View->Clear Slices` is grey, and right clicking the slice shows grey `delete slice` option. After promoting this auto-slice into user-slice, the `delete slice` option is accessible, but after deleting the promoted user-slice, I get back the auto-slice.

[image]

How do I manage to delete this slice? I am using Photoshop CS5.

Comment: I do not know why but the slice accidently disappeared.

Comment: If you reopened the file the slice should have disappeared. If you have your first slice selecting the whole area I don't think there's a way to get rid of it.

Comment: @MickNGarrett: Yes, i reopened the file and the slice disappeared. No, I didn't select the whole area as the first slice. I select part of the image as the first slice, and then Photoshop generated the other slices automatically. But after I deleted the first slice, the 01 slice remained.

Comment: Right. So you deleted all but the first slice. You can't delete that one once you've gotten started with slices unless you reopen the file. That's just the default behavior. Either ignore it or reopen the file.

Comment: @MikeNGarret: repeat your answer in "Your answer". So Jichao can be approved as answerif it is what he needed :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't delete the slice that remains once you've deleted all other slices. You need to reopen the file to hide it. That's just the default behavior. Either ignore it or reopen the file.

Comment: This is not the way. It doesn't work unsurprisingly.

Comment: That's correct, atilkan. Things have changed in the last 5 years. Now Photoshop CC has a handy button in the top bar named "Hide Auto Slices." Toggling this button will hide your first slice.

Answer (score 3):

ctrl+h is the most handy thing

Comment: While ctrl+h *hides* the slices (or more specifically: what you've specified under the View -> Show), this won't *delete* it.

Comment: @koiyu the "main" slice will always be there, it can't be deleted (just hidden), so this is a valid answer.

Comment: @yisela If it can't be deleted the only valid answer is "It can't be deleted". Hiding is not deleting.